# Flash Builder MXML auto-brackets, quotes etc

Tags: flash-builder, mxml, brackets

Any idea what is the setting in Flash Builder 4.5/4.6 to automatically close the "Strings", [brackets], {Braces} for the MXML 
code as in eclipse for the Java code ?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, there's no setting in Flash Builder to auto-insert closing quotes/brackets/braces. Eclipse generally makes this feature language-specific, so it has to be specifically implemented for MXML – the feature seen in other languages like Java doesn't automatically "carry over" to MXML, AS, etc.

I looked into whether the "Code Templates" feature could be used to give you a quick shortcut for inserting pairs like `{}`, but it doesn't look like that will work.

However, you *can* get `""` auto-inserted for MXML attributes: if you use autocomplete to enter the attribute name, the `=""` will be automatically generated after it. (If this isn't working for you, check Preferences > Flash Builder > Editors > MXML Code and make sure "Insert closing quote when completing attributes" is checked).

Answer (score 0):

I use to have the same issue closing braquets, here is the solution for flash builder 4.6, to autoclose strings maybe isn't possible:

In your MXML code editor press mouse rigth click and this menu should open [this](http://grab.by/trBK) menu:

[image: MXML code editor menu]

Select Preferences... and you can select your options in [this](http://grab.by/trBS) window:

[image]